# How to get the creation date of a dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to get the dataset creation date in BigQuery?

I tried bq show but it lists the Last Modified date but not the creation date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--format=prettyjson` for full dataset information ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#debugging)). See the below example with a public dataset:

```sh
$ bq show --format=prettyjson bigquery-public-data:hacker_news | grep creation
  "creationTime": "1457746674484",
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-datasets#schemata_view):

```
SELECT creation_time
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE schema_name = 'datasetId'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metatable `__TABLES__` to get creation date. For example:

```
SELECT table_id, creation_time 
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.__TABLES__`
```